# How can I do clean uninstall, so no settings, extension, etc is left?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My OS: Windows 10

Problem: some weird things are happening, File icons disappeared for example.

Anyway to completely uninstall so I can reinstall from scratch.

I tried just uninstalling, upon reinstalling every setting was there: files, settings, extensions....

Comment: you can uninstall the extensions also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Attention: this will remove your program settings, installed extensions and workspace settings!!!**

**Better make backup first.**

You can try to delete these folders after uninstalling program:

`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` (program folder for user installation)

or

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code` (program folder for 64-Bit-Windows)

or

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code` (program folder for 32-Bit-Windows)

`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.vscode` (installed extensions)

`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Code` (program settings, workspace settings)

And then reinstall.