# Why is the VS Code terminal adding cr-lf characters to the initial prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed Win 10 1809 on my Dell PC, and it seems to run okay. But now there is a problem with the terminal. After the 1809 install, the first thing I did was start up VS Code. I wanted to run yarn start for my React project, but I had to type it way down in the terminal window, while the prompt was at the top. The screen clip below shows the terminal display after I enter "yarn start". The typed input shows up way down from the initial prompt, and the blank area is a long string of "0D0A" characters. Can this be fixed? I did uninstall and reinstall VSCode, but no fix.

[image]

In the screen grab shown above, you can see the space that is filled with "0D0A" characters.

Comment: What is specified in the `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` setting? What plugins are installed? Have you tried a [clean reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175984/7676971)?

Comment: @Victor, This is the setting: "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe". I just disabled all my extensions and reloaded, but still have the same problem. After I do my first command, the next prompt does not have this spacing, so it looks normat from then on. The CLS command just creates a new prompt at the displaced position.

Comment: Сorrect `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` setting is: `// Command Prompt
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"` (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows). If it does not help, then I advise you to perform a clean reinstall (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166530/how-can-i-do-clean-uninstall-so-no-settings-extension-etc-is-left/49175984#49175984).

Comment: Changing the "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" didn't help. I'm putting off doing a clean reinstall because of the hassle.