# How to Change VS Code Code.exe Path for Update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Windows 10] I have "Microsoft VS Code (User Setup)" installed in a custom directory and whenever I try to update it this shows up:

[image: Error Prompt 1]

and then this

[image: Error Prompt 2]

```
Log Info

Dec 23 11:42:40.673 INFO Starting: C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe, false
Dec 23 11:42:40.674 ERRO Bad arguments: Code path doesn't seem to exist: C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

How do I change the path to point it to the right directory where "Code.exe" exists?

Comment: Can you attach a log file that is listed at the bottom of the error window?

Comment: @Victor S. Oops, forgot to put in the Log Info, Thank you for reminding me. Edited and Inserted.

Comment: Is the path in the Windows Path variable correct?

Comment: @VictorS. I changed it to the proper directory (Yes, and restarted) but whenever I run VS Code and try to update, it automatically changes my path back to "C:\Users\jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin" (Which is NOT the right directory!). Why is that??

Comment: You can try reinstall https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175984/7676971.

Comment: @VictorS. is there any other way to fix this instead of just doing the good ol' reinstall?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem recently. **I ended up reinstalling VS Code.**

#### Do I lose my settings?

**No.** Note that I did *not* uninstall VS Code, I just downloaded the installer from the website and installed VSCode. This won't hurt, as **it does not touch your settings and extensions**.

---

#### What I tried

I first tried to visit the path mentioned in the error log, and I noticed that the folder `_` within that directory contained the new VS Code version, downloaded by the updater.

So the path should have been `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_\Code.exe` instead, perhaps.

I tried to move all files from `_` to their parent directory, and then, in VS Code, *Help » Restart to update*. This opened the new version of VS Code, but after closing it and starting it from the original install location (or through a shortcut I have always been using), the old version was still loaded. So apparently, this "trick" didn't work.

Then I tried to make a symbolic link to `Code.exe` within the `_` directory, so the VS Code updater would find Code.exe. This caused roughly the same things to happen. So, this didn't work either.

At last, I decided to just download VS Code from their website, and simply install it. This seemed the most simple option to me.

Comment: Did you install it in the same custom folder as before? Or did you install it in the default location (somewhere in C:)?

Comment: @ArvindhMani If I remember correctly, the installer didn't even ask the install location, as I chose to reinstall.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I did the same thing and noticed that my old VSCode install folder (the one with the "_") was unaffected. So in effect, I had two `Code` executables after the reinstall. I wasn't really comfortable with that and ended up fully uninstalling and re-installing (to the default location this time).

Comment: I had to use the System Installer, not the User Installer (which is currently downloaded with the unmarked big button on the website), in order to be able to choose a custom installation directory. I'm not sure which version/installer I had before.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hard link for Code.exe using mklink, works for me.

Command should look like this (depends where your custom installation is, my in C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/):

```
mklink /H "C:/Users/$username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe" "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe"
```

Comment: I got: The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive. My VSCode is on D: