# How can I change the update path for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, auto-update

Essentially the same query as [How to Change VS Code Code.exe Path for Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901556) , as shown by 'Similar questions'.

Is there any registry value (I am not familiar with such, so it may be a trivial doubt) that I can change so that 'Restart to Update' doesn't reference C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe, and instead to my custom location?

Could I set the install location manually, instead of the default User Setup, if I am forced to reinstall the application?