# How can I get VSCode debugging to work after a Windows system restore?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am under Windows 10 1809. Because of a problem with a Windows update, I had to do a system restore to go back a week. I think the restore deleted more than what it told me it would do. Afterwards when I started my VSCode project, I got an alert that my VSCode program was damaged and I should reinstall it, which I did. Then in my React app I saw that its state had also be restored back by a week! A new file I had built was missing. Anyway I managed to reconstruct my app by using the tools from Dropbox to recover deleted files, and my app now runs as before. But now my existing launch.json file doesn't work. Here is the code from my launch.json:

```
{
  "name": "Chrome React",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
  "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.chrome",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  },
  "breakOnLoad": true
},
```

This has worked daily for me for months, but now when I hit F5, it tries to start but just quits. I get this error from OUTPUT:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:/Users/Bruce/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.11.2/out/src/chromeDebug.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at [eval]:1:41
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:91:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:8:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
```

I went to 'c:/Users/Bruce/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.11.2/out/src/chromeDebug.js', but there was no /src folder at the /out folder. Luckily, I have an external harddrive with a backup made just before this problem appeared. From the backup, I was able to copy over the missing /src folder. But still no success. Now I get this error message.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode-chrome-debug-core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Bruce\.vscode\extensions\msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.11.2\out\src\chromeDebug.js:6:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Bruce\.vscode\extensions\msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome-4.11.2\out\src\chromeDebug.js:34:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
```

Now I think this is all from the system restore. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the Debugger for Chrome extension; that didn't work. How do I create vscode-chrome-debug-core and fix this?

**UPDATE 2/22/19**
This problem has prevented me from working on my project. So as an experiment, I installed VSCode Insiders. And it works perfectly. Now I can run in debug mode without a problem. VSCode Insiders picked up all my installed extensions and settings. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the normal VSCode and the Debugger For Chrome extension, but that didn't work. Something is different somewhere, but I don't know where or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Solved it by navigating to:

> C:\Users\%username%\

Deleting the folder:

> .vscode

And restarting VSCode. This will delete all your user settings, paths and preferences. Make sure you don't have any settings sync extension running as it can corrupt VSCode again.

Comment: I found basically the same advice at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166530/how-can-i-do-clean-uninstall-so-no-settings-extension-etc-is-left/49175984#49175984. But since I was working ok with VSCode Insiders, and planned to buy a new computer in the near future, where I would install every thing from scratch, I did nothing. Still waiting to buy the new computer.